# Issue converting Access SQL Inner Join Query to mySQL Query

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mariadb

I am having trouble finding the syntax issue that is causing the following query to give me no results:

```
SELECT Table1.Country, Table_Data2.Part, Table_Data2.Description, Sum(Table_Data2.Quantity) AS Quantity, Table1.ship_time
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table_Data2 ON Table1.CodeValue = Table_Data2.CodeValue
GROUP BY Table1.Country, Table_Data2.Part, Table_Data2.Description, Table1.ship_time
HAVING (((Table_Data2.Part)="BB1234" Or (Table_Data2.Part)="BB-3454") AND ((Table1.ship_time)=Date()));
```

Which should successfully result in a table that looks like this:

[Example of what result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of2b4.png)

Instead there are no syntax issues that arise nor are there any records that load.

It seems theres a syntax issue in the code above as it does not work in mySQL as it does in MS Access

Comment: To get current date in MySQL, use `Current_Date()`. `Date()` function in MySQL has different behaviour

Comment: Yes I’ve adjusted that, but besides that anything else that stands out?

Comment: Moreover looking at your conditions in the `Having` clause, they are more suited to be used in the `Where` clause. Because they are not aggregated values and you are grouping on these same fields as well. You query will become more performant if you shift them to Where clause

Comment: I appreciate your help, can you please put this in an answer?

Comment: What is the datatype of `ship_time` after converting to MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections possible:

- To get current date in MySQL, use `Current_Date()`. `Date()` function in MySQL has different behaviour, as it is used to extract date part out of a date(time) expression.
- Parentheses around just field names are unnecessary. Use aliasing in multi table query for code clarity and read ability.
- Moreover looking at your conditions in the Having clause, they are more suited to be used in the Where clause. Because they are not aggregated values and you are grouping on these same fields as well. You query will become more performant if you shift them to Where clause, as MySQL will be aggregating on filtered (reduced) data, and thus minimizing temp table space.
- Also, you can rewrite multiple `OR` conditions on same field as `IN(...)`

You can rewrite as:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Country, 
  t2.Part, 
  t2.Description, 
  Sum(t2.Quantity) AS Quantity, 
  t1.ship_time
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table_Data2 AS t2
  ON t1.CodeValue = t2.CodeValue
WHERE 
  t2.Part IN ('BB1234', 'BB-3454')
  AND t1.ship_time = Current_Date()
GROUP BY 
  t1.Country,
  t2.Part,
  t2.Description,
  t1.ship_time
```